# Showing set is closed under addition

Tags: linear-algebra

let $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$ be nonzero vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ and $Q=\{\vec{w}\in \mathbb R^3: \vec{w}\cdot \vec{u}=0 \text{ and }\vec{w}\cdot \vec{v}=0\}$. Show that $Q$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$

How do you show it is closed under vector addition with the condition.

Comment: To show $Q$ is closed under addition, you have to show that for any two $w_1, w_2 \in Q$ you have $w_1+w_2 \in Q$, meaning that $ u \cdot  (w_1+w_2)=0$ and $ v \cdot (w_1+w_2)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $Q$ is closed under addition, suppose that $\vec{w}, \vec{w}'$ are both in $Q$.  You now need to prove that $\vec{w}+\vec{w}'$ is in $Q$.

Hypotheses: $\vec{w}\cdot \vec{u}=0, \vec{w}'\cdot \vec{u}=0, \vec{w}\cdot \vec{v}=0, \vec{w}'\cdot \vec{v}=0$.

Desired conclusion: $(\vec{w}+\vec{w}')\cdot \vec{u}=0$ and $(\vec{w}+\vec{w}')\cdot \vec{v}=0$.

I leave it to you how to make the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $w_1,w_2\in Q$, then $w_1+w_2\in Q\iff (w_1+w_2)\cdot u = 0$ and $(w_1+w_2)\cdot v=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: To show that $Q$ is closed under vector addition, you only show that given two vectors $\vec{a}, \vec{b}\in Q$ satisfying $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{u}=0$ , $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{v}=0$, $\vec{b}\cdot \vec{u}=0$ and $\vec{b}\cdot$ $\vec{v}=0$ for $u,v\in \mathbb{R}^3$, then $\vec{a}+ \vec{b}\in Q$. To do this, you only show that $$u \cdot (\vec{a}+\vec{b})=0$$ and $$v \cdot (\vec{a}+\vec{b})=0.$$